# Un-install a toolbar from Safari

Tags: macos, browser-addons, safari, toolbar

I have installed a toolbar on Safari that I want removed. I don't have the setup of it now and the toolbar is not working properly.

> [image: toolbar on safari]

What do I do to uninstall the toolbar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you can uninstall the Safari toolbar:

> 1. Open the Finder application and browse to Applications.
> 2. Scroll down to Toolbars and click on .
> 3. Double-click on “Uninstall”.
> 4. Fill in the “User name & Password” and click the OK button.

If that doesn't work, try to drag the Toolbars folder to the trash bin.

Comment: Done. Working perfectly. Thanks for your help.